# Change Badge color according to status from jquery ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, frontend

I am getting some data from an endpoint using a get request, I want to use the status of the request to change the color of the request status.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'api/v1/service/tax',
    success: (result)=>{
        let output="";
        let serialNumber = 1;

        for (var i in result){
          output+= `<tr class="custom-table-rows">
                        <th scope="row">${serialNumber++}</th>
                        <td>${result[i].entityName}</td>
                        <td>${result[i].serviceName}</td>
                        <td>${result[i].dateRequested}</td>
                        <td><span class="badge badge-pill">${result[i].status}</span></td>
                    </tr>`
            if(result[i].status === 'PENDING'){
                $('span.badge').addClass('badge-danger');
            } else if(result[i].status === 'IN PROCESS'){
                $('span.badge').addClass('badge-warning');
            }else{
                $('span.badge').addClass('badge-success');
            }
        }

        $("#adminTable").html(output);
    }
  });
```

Here is my code and that is the conditional statement I am using to check the loop. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add to your question what `result` is? Is it an array? Have you verified it is? Is the URL you get data from, providing JSON? And exactly what is not going like you want it to? Errors?

Comment: > What am i doing wrong? - How do you say you are doing something wrong?

Comment: What you are doing wrong is, you are using jquery selectors to change the badge class which wont work because the html you are generating is still in the variable `output` and has not been added to the DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Do it in the following way

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'api/v1/service/tax',
    success: (result)=>{
        let output="";
        let serialNumber = 1;
        let badge = "";

        for (var i in result){
          output+= `<tr class="custom-table-rows">
                        <th scope="row">${serialNumber++}</th>
                        <td>${result[i].entityName}</td>
                        <td>${result[i].serviceName}</td>
                        <td>${result[i].dateRequested}</td>`

            if(result[i].status === 'PENDING'){
                badge = 'badge-danger' ;
            } else if(result[i].status === 'IN PROCESS'){
                badge = 'badge-warning' ;
            }else{
                badge = 'badge-success' ;
            }
         output+= `<td><span class="badge badge-pill ${badge}">${result[i].status}</span></td></tr>`
        }

        $("#adminTable").html(output);
    }
  });
```

Explanation: What you are doing wrong is, you are using jQuery selectors to change the badge class which wont work because the html you are generating is still in the variable `output` and has not been added to the DOM.
jQuery Selectos are used to select and Manipulate the elements present in the DOM

Comment: This is the exact solution. Thank you!!

Comment: You are Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Here the problem is .badge span is not created in DOM and you are selecting the not created span in the loop. DOM create after '$("#adminTable").html(output);' this statement.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'api/v1/service/tax',
  success: (result) => {
    let output = "";
    let serialNumber = 1;

    for (var i in result) {
      output += '<tr class="custom-table-rows"> <
        th scope = "row" > $ {
          serialNumber++
        } < /th> <
        td > $ {
          result[i].entityName
        } < /td> <
        td > $ {
          result[i].serviceName
        } < /td> <
        td > $ {
          result[i].dateRequested
        } < /td> <
        td > < span class = "badge badge-pill '
      if (result[i].status === 'PENDING') {
        output += 'badge-danger';
      } else if (result[i].status === 'IN PROCESS') {
        output += 'badge-warning';
      } else {
        output += 'badge-success';
      }
      output += '">${result[i].status}</span></td> </tr>';
    }

    $("#adminTable").html(output);
  }
});
```

Comment: This was very helpful Thank you.